# text animation for on a particular section

Tags: javascript, css

I have a one page website on which I have used one page-scroll JavaScript. I want to show animation on text when that particular section get loaded. The animation start working as soon as page loads but not working when section loads

```
 <section class="page6" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
              <h2 style="font-size: 5em; text-align: justify;">Networking for artists</h2><br>
              <h2 style="float: left; font-size: 4em; color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">By artists</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @ Aashima Vinayak what have you done ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that check if your particular section its in viewport. After that call this function on scroll event.

```
 function isInViewport(particularSection) {
    if (
        window.pageYOffset >= particularSection.offsetTop - particularSection.offsetHeight / 2 &&
        window.pageYOffset <= particularSection.offsetTop + particularSection.offsetHeight / 2
        ) {
        return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
};



 window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if(isInViewport(particularSection)){
        // put a class on section to start animation
    }
})
```